# Basic malloc, array, pointer and assignment error

Tags: c

I have the following code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{

    char *buf = malloc(sizeof(char *) *3);
    char *p = "print";
    char *q = "quit";
    char *r = "reverse";
    
    buf[0] = p;
    buf[1] = q;
    buf[2] = r;
    
    printf("%s", buf[0]);
      
    return 0;

}
```

I think `buf` will save the address of `char` variable.
So, as `p` indicates the address of string, i think i can assign `p` to `buf[0]`.
But compiler says "assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast".
Why this happens?

Comment: `buf` is a pointer to an sequence of `char`s, but you trying to write `char*`s to it. You want to make `buf` a `char**`. The error about converting a pointer to an integer occurs at `buf[0] = p`, since you're attempting to implicitly convert a pointer `p` to an integer type to assign to `buf[0]`, which has type `char`.

Comment: Thank you very much! I think I will not forget this after

Comment: Change to `char **buf = malloc(sizeof *buf * 3);`  (note: `**`).

Answer (score 0):

first : you are trying to assign a `char *` to `char` instead you must use the following code

```
char **buf = (char **)malloc(sizeof(char *) * 3);
```

credit @chux

Comment: you can replace the `sizeof(char) * 6)` with `strlen("print")`

Comment: That's I thought he won't use strlen that's why I wrote 6 instead of strlen("print").
about why I add 1 cuz strlen("print") will return 5 and I add one for the `\0`

Comment: `"print"` is a string constant, you don't need to allocate space for it with `malloc()` in order to assign its address to a pointer variable. This answer would be much improved if you delete everything after the first point (and credit @chux for the first part).

Comment: @Caleb yeah, that's why a give him two options the first without allocating and the second with malloc.
cuz I don't think what he did is right (talking about the `char *p = "print";`

Comment: There's nothing at all wrong with `char *p = "print";`... that's valid C. Good edit.

Comment: oh thank you for your info, I didn't know that